# i can't access my files of my angular project during deployment

Tags: json, angular, typescript, deployment, serve

i'm trying to deploy my web application with frontend: angular
but i can't access my JSON file in assets folder

so this is the funstion to get data from JSON file

```
getLanguage()
  {
    let language=localStorage.getItem('language')
    if (!language)
      language = 'english'
    return this.http.get('www/dist/assets/languages/'+language+'.json')
  }
}
```

and this is the path of the file in my server :
[image]

i'm trying to access the file JSON in my server
but i can't , i don't if its' an URL problem or something else ?

Comment: did you try 'assets/languages/'+language+'.json'?

Comment: yep yep i tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment on your question, this should work:

```
return this.http.get('assets/languages/'+language+'.json')
```

The folder is relative to your application folder (`src` folder at dev time).

You also need to ensure that the assets folder is defined in the angular.json file.

Under `"architect"` and `"build"`, ensure you have something that looks like this:

```
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: i check my angular.json file and i found that those lines already exist :
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
i tried this : return this.http.get('assets/languages/'+language+'.json')
but didn't work

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error message? A 404 not found or something else? Is `language` valid for the case you are trying?

Comment: yeah i got 404 not found
it didn't recognize the path : assets/languages/english.json 
i even tried to add the domain but still not found
i also added the relative path .. in vain

Comment: If you run it locally (in a debugger) does it work? Just not when deployed?

Comment: yes it works  locally correctly

Comment: Since I'd run out of ideas, I posted the question to Google's generative AI. It provided the following suggestion: "Check the file permissions to make sure that the Angular application has read access to the JSON file." (Though I would think that would be a security error then and not a 404). Also, do you have a base-href set? It should be in your index.html file.

Comment: I also just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959975/unable-to-read-json-file-in-angular-application-using-http-client-in-cloud-appli. It suggests confirming that the server is configured to read JSON files.

Comment: yep yep i have base-href set
thanks , i will chek the configuration of the server

Answer (score 0):

try
`return this.http.get('./assets/languages/'+language+'.json')`

that is add `./` before `assets/`